# GLSL homogeneous transformation issues

Tags: vector, matrix, glsl, homogenous-transformation

I'm trying to transform a point represented by a column `vec3` by a homogeneous `mat4` in GLSL. The matrix is a simple translation by 1 along the x axis. I've checked as best as I could that the matrix indeed makes it to my shader as a proper column-major matrix of this form:

```
1 0 0 1
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1
```

I first tried `(matrix * vec4(point, 1)).xyz`, however I did not see the effect of the translation in my scene. At some point, out of despair, I reimplemented this transformation in different ways that seem equivalent to me, and found one that did what I wanted. However, I am at loss to figure out why only that one works:

```
#version 140
vec3 transformPoint(vec3 point, mat4 matrix)
{
    return (matrix * vec4(point, 1)).xyz;

    return mat3(matrix[0].xyz, matrix[1].xyz, matrix[2].xyz) * point
        + matrix[3].xyz;

    return matrix[0].xyz * point.x
        + matrix[1].xyz * point.y
        + matrix[2].xyz * point.z
        + matrix[3].xyz;

    // This works, but is not a full transformation
    return point + matrix[3].xyz;

    // Only this one works
    matrix = transpose(matrix);
    return vec3(
        dot(matrix[0], vec4(point, 1)),
        dot(matrix[1], vec4(point, 1)),
        dot(matrix[2], vec4(point, 1)));
}
```

Weirdly, the non-working transformations have an effect if I use a Y translation, but none on an X translation.

I hope I'm just overlooking something obvious. Any ideas?

**Update**:

I've done some more tests and `vector * transpose(matrix)` does not give the same result as `matrix * vector`. What's going on?

Comment: What GPU are you testing on? I have had some bad results on Qualcomm Adreno 320 doing matrix post multiplication.

Comment: @nmr Mmmh it's been a while but it was either a GeForce 525M or an Intel HD 4400 GPU.

Answer (score 1):

Without additional information on how you initialize your mat4 variable before calling transformPoint(). I'm guessing it's very likely that the matrix you passed in is in row major order while the matrice in glsl by default are all in column major. This explains why it only works after transpose(matrix).